# Ruby push a hash into an array with out curly braces

Tags: arrays, ruby, append, splat

I am trying to create a parameter list for use in a function call.

The function call looks like the following:

```
render json: @flight, meta: {url: Flight.encrypt(@flight.id.to_s)}
```

I tried the following:

```
params = [key1: value1] 
params.push(key2: value2)
```

In hopes of using the splat operator (`*`) to populate the parameter list.  However, params looks like the following:

```
[{key1: value1},{key2: value2}]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

## Edit

I updated the example code to add more context.

The function call looks like the following:

```
render json: some_json_value, meta: {some_key:  some_value}
```

I tried the following:

```
params = [json: @some_json_value] 
params.push(meta: {some_key:  some_value})
```

In hopes of using the splat operator (`*`) to populate the parameter list.  However, params looks like the following:

```
[{json: @some_json_value},{meta: {some_key:  some_value}}]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could include the `desired in/output`, in this case the code you would like to execute (I suspect `render *params`). Would make your question clearer (to me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You method expects an hash (not an array of hashes). Therefore you have to use a hash to build your params:

```
parameters = { :key1 => value1 }
parameters[:key2] = value2

somefunction parameters
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that, but the result for parameters is `{key1: value1, key2: value2}`.  I need `key1: value1, key2: value2`

Comment: @user2517182: "key1: value1, key2: value2" is not an object. You need to learn to differentiate simplified syntax for something and the actual thing that syntax will produce. Depending on how your method is implemented, it accepts either one hash or keyword arguments. You can use a hash to call both variants.

Comment: @user2517182: seeing your edit, this answer is exactly what you need. You didn't even try it.

Comment: this is what i thought.  I have done it many times.  however, when I called render function with {key1: value1, key2: value2} there is a syntax error `syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i did try it.  This is why I wrote the edit.

Comment: @user2517182: you call it with literal hash, or use a variable? If literal hash, either add parentheses to the method call, or remove curly braces.

Comment: @user2517182 Well, you have to try better. This works.

Comment: @user2517182: JFYI, you don't need the splat here. Nor the array. Just one hash.

Comment: @user2517182: I updated my answer. I guess you are working with an older version of Ruby, given the error message `syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'` The hash syntax with the `:` is only valid in newer Ruby versions. Whereas the version with the `=>` works in all versions of Ruby.

Comment: @spickermann: nope. That is what you get when you do this: `foo {key1: 1, key2: 'bar'}`

Answer (score 0):

First what come to mind:

```
[{key1: value1},{key2: value2}].inject(:merge)
#=> {key1: value1, key2: value2}
```